# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with highest priority

Tags: spring-boot

in my Spring Boot project I have the default `application.properties` in resources directory, I also configured Spring to load a properties file from file system (in working directory), called `config.properties`. some properties are redefined in the `config.properties` file, I want them have higher priority and overwrite properties defined in application.properties.

here is the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties =
                new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("config.properties"));
        properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
        properties.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

but it does not work. the values in `application.properties` are applied, not `config.properties`. I tried to change `setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);` to             `setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);` nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can try call the method PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocalOverride(boolean localOverride)

```
properties.setLocalOverride(true)
```

See for details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE_to_4.2.0.RC1/Spring%20Framework%204.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setLocalOverride-boolean-